# How do we check for "Enable Email Tracking" Option in APEX?

Tags: apex, enhanced-emails, email-tracking

I would like to check and learn if Email Tracking is enabled in the organization.

I was hoping this setting (as highlighted below screenshot) would be available from an Object in org schema somewhere. I looked for it in Organization or at User level but I found none.

Can someone guide me if this is stored somewhere and is readable in APEX code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can access it from the [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi). You will find this setting in [ActivitiesSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm). There is no *direct* access to this setting in Apex code.

Comment: That's sad :( ... That api route is troublesome mostly, if you wanna use it via Lightning Component. Session Id is restricted for API execution in this mode.